# how to disable a file drop box?

Tags: angular

I use `disabled=true` to disable a file-drop box but it does not work. I still can drop a file in it.

This file-drop is an Angular 2+ component

```
           <file-drop (click)="file.click()" dropZoneLabel="Drag & Drop file here!" (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)" (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)"
                (onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)" disabled="true">
            </file-drop>
```

Comment: Assuming you're using [this component](https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop/blob/master/src/lib/ngx-drop/file-drop.component.ts), it looks like the `disabled` attribute only blocks drag-and-drop for some reason (note that the `onBrowseButtonClick` function doesn't check it).

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `disabled="true"` to `[disabled]="true"`

Comment: I still can click to open a file dialog. However, I tried another property [showBrowseBtn]="true", and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work with *ngIf="false"

`<file-drop (click)="file.click()" dropZoneLabel="Drag & Drop file here!" (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)" (onFileOver)="fileOver($event)"
                    (onFileLeave)="fileLeave($event)" *ngIf="false">`